# Dependency injection on object created in return statement

Tags: oop, dependency-injection

Using PHP as an example, if I have a function like this:

```
public function foo() {

    return new CustomException($this->message);

}
```

Is dependency injection possible here? CustomException is not created until the function is called therefore cannot be passed as a parameter.

EDIT: Sorry if I haven't explained it very well. My question is specifically: how can I inject CustomException as a dependency on this class when the object is not created until *after* the function is called?

Comment: Not sure I understsand your question. What are you trying to achieve here ? If this is just about passing the message your can set it in your class by constructor injection.

Comment: @Shinosha: The question asks "I don't want to hardcode `new CustomException` in there, but how can I use DI to construct it? Keep in mind that `foo` might never be called".

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand what you are asking. An Exception is just an object. It is not thrown until it is thrown. That means, you can simply create the instance and pass it to the consumer as needed. If you want to defer the creation of the Exception, create a Factory for it and inject that. In languages having Anonymous Functions, you can also wrap the new keyword into the function and pass that around then.